# How to update partial objects in an array of objects in mongo-db using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I want to update request fields only in an array using java.This is my existing document in mongo db:

```
{
    "_id" : "6691e5068dwe335w42cb0a699650f",
    "Opportunity_Owner" : "Self",
    "Account_Name" : "IC",
    "Lead_Source" : "Callbox",
    "Opportunity_Name" : "name1 ",
    "Stage" : "Proposal",
    "Stage_Status" : "A",
    "1555570551211" : [],
    "1555556165153" : [],
    "1555556059584" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1557389940585",
            "Notes" : "Note 1"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1557389945398",
           "Notes" : "Hi Bobby "
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1557389978181",
            "Notes" : "Spoken to Bobby."
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1557389990159",
            "Notes" : "plan to call on 29/Apr"
        }
    ],
    
    "createdBy" : "2c18b8dbb7d74a41a66f53a90117480a",
    "createdDate" : "1562911250917"
}
```

Request payload:

```
{
 "_id" : "6691e5068dwe335w42cb0a699650f",
 "Stage_Status" : "I",
 "1555556059584" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1557389940585",
            "Notes" : "updated note 123"
        }
     ]
}
```

I am trying to update  "Stage_Status" and "1555556059584.Notes"  at a time  using $set.I am able to update "Stage_Status" but "1555556059584" array is going to reset with what i have updated with last one.

My except output :

```
{
    "_id" : "6691e5068dwe335w42cb0a699650f",
    "Opportunity_Owner" : "Self",
    "Account_Name" : "IC",
    "Lead_Source" : "Callbox",
    "Opportunity_Name" : "name1 ",
    "Stage" : "Proposal",
    "Stage_Status" : "I",
    "1555570551211" : [],
    "1555556165153" : [],
    "1555556059584" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1557389940585",
            "Notes" : "updated note 123"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1557389945398",
           "Notes" : "Hi Bobby "
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1557389978181",
            "Notes" : "Spoken to Bobby."
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "1557389990159",
            "Notes" : "plan to call on 29/Apr"
        }
    ],
    
    "createdBy" : "2c18b8dbb7d74a41a66f53a90117480a",
    "createdDate" : "1562911250917"
}
```

can any one please help me to figure it out in java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this using the different Updates options provided by Mongo Java client. Just try exploring `pullByFilter` to filter out the document that you need to replace and then use `push` method to push the new document to the array. You can try these method instead of using simple `set` method.

For detailed documentation , please refer this link https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/?com/mongodb/client/model/Updates.html.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```java
database.getCollection("yourCollection")
    // you want to update one element
    .updateOne( 
        // you identify the element to update with its _id
        Filters.eq("_id", "6691e5068dwe335w42cb0a699650f"),
        // you want to perform several updates operations
        Updates.combine(
            // first you update the "Stage_Status" property of your element
            Updates.set("Stage_Status", "I"),
            // this is the tricky part: you look for an element inside the array 1555556059584 and you want to update its "Notes" property
            Updates.set("1555556059584.$[note].Notes", "updated note 123") 
        ),
        // finally, the options below specify which element of the array you want to update: you filter with the id property of the elements.
        new UpdateOptions().arrayFilters(Arrays.asList(
            Filters.eq("note.id", "1557389940585")
        ))
    );
```